# Postgres backup data with PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, batch-file

I try to backup database with PHP script. My idea was to run the pg_dump with PHP as a batch file. (Yes I am using PHP for Windows).

I write this code:

```
$content = "set BACKUP_FILE=database.backup \r\n" .
            "SET PGPASSWORD=" . COF_DATABASE_PASSWORD . "\r\n" . 
            "pg_dump -i -U " . COF_DATABASE_USERNAME . " -F c -b -v -f %BACKUP_FILE% " . COF_DATABASE_NAME . "\r\n" .
            "echo done";

    file_put_contents($root . "/Files/Updates/Backup.bat", $content);
    $system = exec ($root . "/Files/Updates/Backup.bat", $result);
    pclose(popen("start /B $root/Files/Updates/Backup.bat", "r"));
    $result = shell_exec($root . "/Files/Updates/Backup.bat");
```

The Backup.dat file is created. If I run it manually from windows, the database.backup file is created, but not when I try to run the batch from PHP.
For both command I get in $result:

> (string:241)  D:\Data\WWW...\Process>set BACKUP_FILE=database.backup
>
> D:\Data\WWW...\Process>SET PGPASSWORD=dom123
>
> D:\Data\WWW...\Process>pg_dump -i -U dom -F c -b -v -f
>   database.backup  dom

Once as array (exec) and once as string (shell_exec).

Then I was thinking that running bat file (even if I created in code and then delete) is not the brightest idea (security). So I way trying to backup database with SQL-s (PDO - execute ...)

But I can not find any documentation if this is even possible. All solutions propose pg_dump. Is there any SQL command to backup entire database to file?

I am looking for a working solution. SQL or .bat, doesn't matters at this point.

**Edited:**

Also try:

```
$string = "export PGPASSWORD=" . COF_DATABASE_PASSWORD . " && export PGUSER=" . COF_DATABASE_USERNAME . " && pg_dump -h localhost db_name " . COF_DATABASE_NAME . " > " . $root . "Files/Updates/Backup.sql && unset PGPASSWORD && unset PGUSER"; 
    exec($string);
    shell_exec($string);
```

**Edited (answer on Craig Ringer):**

Try your code, I get error. [image]
1: Catch all for general errors from [this page](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/exitcodes.html)

For image open link in new tab to get full size.

Comment: I'm not a *PHP* guy, but I don't understand what the use of *PHP* is giving you here. Why not just use a *batch* file to execute the pg_* commands? They seem to be fairly static, so the level of indirection with *PHP* seems unnecessary (and, as you're experiencing, error-prone).

Comment: @Ken Hampson: I am updating site with PHP and before I do this, I want to backup files to zip (DONE) and backup database. Just in case. I call update on page, then from ajax request call another page:

pclose(popen("start /B ". "php d:\WWW\Update.php", "r"));  

witch process the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any SQL command to backup entire database to file?

No. It'd be nice, but there isn't one.

> I am looking for a working solution. SQL or .bat, doesn't matters at this point.

Don't use a batch file. Instead, either set environment variables in your local process and then CreateProcess `pg_dump` directly [or use a `.pgpass` file, which is `pgpass.conf` on Windows](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html).

### Direct execution

Rather than using a batch file, execute pg_dump directly after setting the environment.

This is made harder because PHP is awful, it lacks anything sane like `execv` to exec with an array of arguments. You *should* be able to just:

```
# DOES NOT WORK, as exec(...) doesn't take an array argument:
putenv("PGPASSWORD=" . COF_DATABASE_PASSWORD);
$dumpcmd = array("pg_dump", "-i", "-U", COF_DATABASE_USERNAME, "-F", "c", "-b", "-v", "-f", COF_BACKUP_FILE, COF_DATABASE_NAME);
exec($dumpcmd);
putenv("PGPASSWORD");
```

but PHP doesn't take an array for `exec` and doesn't have `execv`. So you have to munge it into a shell command, dealing with the escaping yourself.

Not even [`proc_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) supports this.

Instead you have to manually escape arguments, e.g.:

```
putenv("PGPASSWORD=" . COF_DATABASE_PASSWORD);
$dumpcmd = array("pg_dump", "-i", "-U", escapeshellarg(COF_DATABASE_USERNAME), "-F", "c", "-b", "-v", "-f", escapeshellarg(COF_BACKUP_FILE), escapeshellarg(COF_DATABASE_NAME));
exec( join(' ', $dumpcmd), $cmdout, $cmdresult );
putenv("PGPASSWORD");
if ($cmdresult != 0)
{
    # Handle error here...
}
```

If you were using a civilized language you could use one of the secure alternatives directly, e.g. `execve`/`CreateProcessEx` (C), `subprocess.check_call` (Python), `Kernel.exec` with an array argument (Ruby), etc.

### Pgpass

You can append lines to the user's `pgpass.conf` file, or require it to be preconfigured. Then `pg_dump` will find the login automatically.

You must still check for errors.

### Batch file

If you must use a batch file, you need to redirect stderr to stdout (since you're probably not capturing it) and also [test `%ERRORLEVEL%` on exit](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php) so you detect a failure of `pg_dump`. e.g.

```
pg_dump -i -U myuser -F c -b -v -f outfile dbname 2>&1

IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0
  GOTO ERROR
exit 0

:ERROR
echo "pg_dump failed, see logs for details"
exit 1
```

then you need to check the return code. `shell_exec` doesn't give you access to that, it only produces the output text, as shown by the "Note" block. So you should use `exec`.

I don't speak Windows Batch File well, and would personally do this with direct execution of `pg_dump`. But then I don't use PHP given a choice either.

Comment: I tried and get error with code 1:  Catchall for general errors Miscellaneous errors, such as "divide by zero"

Comment: @Makla You tried *what*? There's not a single "do this" in the above. So what exactly did you try?

Comment: it is in the image. I edited my original post. Just in case: [link](http://cofovi.si/Files/StackOverflow/BackingDatabase.png)

Comment: @Makla Er, ok, so you used `exec` with an array of parameters joined into a single command. It appears to produce no output. Try appending this extra argument to the array: `2>&1`. What this does is tell the shell (`cmd.exe`) "send standard error to standard output", so PHP can see it because it doesn't know how to capture stderr. Then re-run.

Comment: @Makla Oh duh. Your `pg_dump` probably isn't on the `PATH`. Try explicit path - instead of `pg_dump` write (with changes for install location and version) `%PROGRAMFILES%\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\pg_dump.exe` . (Or try `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\pg_dump.exe` in case env var expansion is a problem)

Comment: I get exactly that in $cmdout:"(string:63) 'pg_dump' is not recognized as an internal or external command," and "(string:31) operable program or batch file."
But that is strange, because I already added to path. I try from command line from many different directories, and dump is working.

Comment: It is not working without path, don't know why, maybe because script is running from d: and the windows are installed on c:, but this is problem for another topic.
THANK YOU.

Answer (score 7):

You can try with the following command. I also have the same problem. I fixed that by using attached code:

```php
<?php
    exec('pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://username:password@127.0.0.1:5432/mydatabase > dbbackup.sql',$output);
    print_r($output);
?>
```